# Can you use detectmobilebrowser to link a stylesheet?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

i'm using detectmobilebrowsers js file for detection on mobile devices ,i also added in the tablets for it , i do not want it for a redirection method so i set the redirect url to original site , i was wanting to use to link a different stylesheet for a few particular devices i have issues with. I've tried using media queries but they won't isolate the specific device.

So , can a script be added to the detectmobiledevice.js where i can link a style sheet , say for an ipad ? if so , not knowing anything about jquery/java can someone illustrate this.

if....ipad {add css}
else....all others {add css}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found this and it works great https://github.com/matthewhudson/device.js

Answer (score 0):

You can use http://rafael.adm.br/css_browser_selector/

Its easy to implement just use specific class